# CocoaPods with Swift Project and Vuforia

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, cocoapods, vuforia

I develop a project with Vuforia SDK.

I use a swift project. In this project, I create some UIViewControllers in Swift and I have one UIViewController based on ImageTargets from Vuforia. Everything works.

Now I try to use Cocoapods for Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. I create PodFile, I install pods, I open xcworkspace.
But when I run the project, I've got errors with frameworks (Alamofire and Swifty).

**Errors : 
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/.../build/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/.../build/Debug-iphoneos/SwiftyJSON'
ld: framework not found Alamofire
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

I try many solutions from Stack but nothing works.

**More informations**. I want to use Alamofire and SwiftyJSON on Swift class only not in objC.

What's wrong ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: I've made it run in one of my projects. Let me arrive home and I'll get to you with the working code!

Comment: Hello @Alex, do you find your working code ? I hope to hear from you. Thanks

Comment: Check it out here. https://github.com/alextarrago/vuforiaswiftpods

Answer (score 0):

OK. I find the solution.

After @Alex Tarrago help, I can use these frameworks after **editing scheme**.

In **Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme**, I select **Build** in left panel. 
After that, I click on **+** and I add the **frameworks**.

All work...
Thank you @Alex for your help...